# How do I dispose inline declared objects

Tags: c#, dispose

I have a large project that utilises inline declared objects for one time use (brushes, colors, fonts etc).

when i run the code analysis tool in VS2010 I am warned that there are objects that dont get disposed on every path.

given the line of code below how can I ensure that the items raised are disposed explicitly when no longer in use or when an exception occurs.

```
g.DrawString(stringNames[i],
     (Font)new Font("Segoe UI", 7, FontStyle.Regular),
     (Brush)Brushes.Black, 
     new Point(hStart.X - 12, hStart.Y - 6));
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ensure your `Graphics` object gets immediately disposed after use by wrapping it inside of a `using` statement.  The same goes for any object implementing `IDisposable`.

```
using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)  // Or wherever you are getting your graphics context
{
    using(Font font = new Font("Segoe UI", 7, FontStyle.Regular))
    {
        g.DrawString(stringNames[i], font, Brushes.Black, new Point(hStart.X - 12, hStart.Y - 6));
    }
}
```

*As a side note, you don't need to explicitly cast the Font or Brush object in your example above.  These are already strongly typed.*

Comment: lots of answers, in the above example would the inline font get disposed when the using statement expires (i.e disposed with the graphics object g) ?

Comment: @DanielGwalter The font will be disposed immediately before the graphics object in this example. They are two seperate using blocks.

Comment: also, thanks for the side note, for future reference how do i find out if an item is already strongly typed before making the same mistake?

Comment: You're constructing an object, (of type Font) -- which will return a Font object. As for the Brush, you're calling a property of the static class Brushes, which returns a Brush object in it's getter.  Because these *types* are exactly what the signature of the DrawString method is calling for, theres no need to cast these to anything else -- and in this example, to what they already are.

Answer (score 2):

You can't dispose an inline declared object, you have to move it out-of-line.

```
using (Font font = new Font(...))
   graphics.DrawString(..., font, ...);
```

However, if you're creating the same font every time you paint, you should consider creating it once and attaching it to Control that uses it.

```
class MyControl : Control
{
    private Font segoe7Font = new Font(...);

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            segoe7Font.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately these really are one time use objects otherwise i would of declared them early and reused them.  the control in question draws a bitmap and uses two fonts and two brushes once only.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't claim unmanaged resources in that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var f = new Font("Segoe UI", 7, FontStyle.Regular))
    g.DrawString(stringNames[i], f, (Brush)Brushes.Black, new Point(hStart.X - 12, hStart.Y - 6));
```

Comment: i guess that the above gives me a reference to the object (f) and that i could dispose f.  what this question has taught me is that the inline method may be quick and easy but that it also adds issues in terms of readability, disposal and possible reuse.